# If we say ignorance is bliss, why do we seek knowledge?

Tags: knowledge

I’ve been thinking about this. 
Answers?

Comment: "We" do not say it. [Gray's poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ode_on_a_Distant_Prospect_of_Eton_College) is conditional:"*where* ignorance is bliss, 'Tis folly to be wise". And it only applies to "knowing their fate"  for those "condemn'd to groan".

Comment: If we say a rolling stone gathers no moss, why do we buy their music?

Comment: @Conifold That may be where the phrase came from, but nowadays it's more often used without the conditional context.

Answer (score 14):

Err... The phrase 'ignorance is bliss' is *sarcastic*. 'Ignorance is bliss' in the sense that one actually believes that the ravenous bug-blatter beast of traal will not eat us if we put a towel over our heads. The phrase is invariably used as a way of chiding someone for being willfully, stupidly, or naïvely ignorant of the way the world actually works, such that the person stumbles around in a thick cloud of false confidence and superficial contentment, awaiting the inevitable, painful prat-fall.

People seek knowledge, because knowledge gives us fundamental understandings of the world that allow us to steer a course around and through problems and obstacles. It gives us a far more honest and real sense of confidence and contentment.

Comment: I don't believe 'ignorance is bliss' is sarcastic in the slightest. Your example of the ravenous bug-blatter beast of traal is much more apt from the angle of an ignorant person having no knowledge that the beast even wants to eat you. I don't know about you, but I would feel much better not knowing of my impending doom than knowing and having to rationalize the fear/anxiety.

Comment: @mascoj — The point is to be cognizant enough to effectively *avoid* that impending doom, right?

Comment: Is it though? Bliss is a state of pure happiness or joy. Knowing of that possible future puts pressure on your psyche to  _change_ how things are to avoid such events.  You can truly live in bliss via ignorance if you never are aware of the alternative paths life can take.

Comment: @mascoj — You've watched *Forrest Gump* too many times...

Comment: But the ravenous bug-blatter beast of traal *won't* eat you if you put a towel over your head...

Comment: @OrangeDog — Please remember that the Hitchhiker's Guide is (in some places) wildly inaccurate.

Comment: In _this_ place, though, its inaccuracy was an incorrect preposition, not the part about towels.  Also note that it was _definitively_ inaccurate, not _wildly_.  As the verdict in the court case held.

Comment: @JdeBP — I'm going to wrap a towel around my head right now and hope that this discussion decides that I am not having it. 

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Conifold's well-informed answer - some knowledge is painful. The poem points out the ironic fact that not knowing ones fate allows one to live a better life.

Examples include knowing what people really think about you, knowing why and when a relationship will end or when you will die. In cases like these, it's often better (smarter) not to know. And that's not because it is not useful information - it would be VERY useful but for our emotions over-riding rational responses to the knowledge.

Interesting question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the premise is true, humans don't necessarily do whatever maximises their personal bliss. Insofar as philosophy comments on this, the question is what construal of our ethical responsibilities we try to live by, when we can bring ourselves to do so. Doing what serves our personal bliss sounds closer to [*egoism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethical_egoism) than any other theory of ethics - a 1-person [consequentialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequentialism), as it were. But people often prefer consequentialism in a more holistic sense, possibly not even limited to fellow people. Or they may act out of [a sense of duty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontological_ethics), or may consider knowledge or critical thinking a [virtue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtue_ethics). And whatever we think as individuals, it seems our societies [tend toward progress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_ethics) rather than short-term pleasure. The unitalicised hyperlinks are to four major philosophical accounts of ethics.